Is this understanding correct: If an object stores everything in itself, copying it and moving it is actually the same thing?
Examples of "objects that stores everything in itself or not" in C++:
using EverythingInMyself1 = int[64];
using EverythingInMyself2 = struct {
    bool flag;
    int head;
    uint8_t data[100];
};

using SomeDataMayNotInMyself1 = std::string;
using SomeDataMayNotInMyself2 = struct {
    bool flag;
    std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]> data;
};

Examples of "objects that stores everything in itself or not" in Rust:
type EverythingInMyself1 = [i32; 64];
struct EverythingInMyself2 {
    flag: bool,
    head: i32,
    data: [u8; 100]
}

type SomeDataMayNotInMyself1 = String;
struct SomeDataMayNotInMyself2 {
    flag: bool,
    data: Vec<u8>
}

True for all stack-and-heap-based memory allocation languages? Because AFAIK move is actually shallow copy. If an object stores everything in itself, deep copy and shallow copy are the same.

Neither of the examples you provide is an object. Also, when asking a code related question, the very first tag you should use should be for the language that you're using. Putting it in the post body is useless. People monitor tags.

This seems like a use-case based scenario, so really depends on what problem you're trying to solve.

And note that ExampleHasHeap2 isn't even copyable. And due to short string optimization (SSO), ExampleHasHeap1 might not use any heap at all.

Also note that std::move doesn't actually move anything. It is essentially a convenience cast. The word is more of a misnomer.

Also using ExampleNoHeap2 = struct{...}; is fancy way of writing struct ExampleNoHeap2{...}; for the most part.

Copying and moving refers to corresponding constructors (assignment operators), it doesn't necessary related to how the objects are allocated.

struct S { S(int v) : v(v) {} int v; S(S const &) = default; S(S&& o) : v(o.v) { o.v = 0; } } copies differently from moving yet it uses no heap.

Are you requiring the code example to actually declaring 4 variables so that "they are objects"? Please, this makes no sense.

What is no heap allocation? Is struct File { int fd = open("path", O_CREAT); ~File() { close(fd); } File(File&& other) : fd(0) { std::swap(fd, other.fd); } }; considered as such?

If you are going to compare multiple languages, I am not sure that there is a universal meaning for "moving" objects. The term has a rather specific meaning in C++ that basically is nothing more than special overload resolution rules for certain kinds of expressions. It has no meaning in the object model and doesn't need to relate to storage duration or memory allocation at all.

@3CxEZiVlQ This is considered "has heap allocation". Because not all data are stored in the struct ifself.

Both "copying" and "moving" mean different things in C++ and Rust. I suggest you focus on one at a time.

You seem to make the assumption that because code look similar in different languages that under the hood  languages do similar things. This is not true.

@PepijnKramer So what do they do? Why are they not similar? Can you elaborate your statement a bit?

For example C# has reference semantics and memory is managed for you by a garbage collector. C++ allows you to either use the stack or dynamically alllocated memory explicitly and lifetime is mostly determined by scopes.  Copying and moving in C++ are not the same concepts. When you move you also transfer "ownership", copying really means that... making a copy (in memory). Reference C++ scope and C++ RAII

There is a lot of imprecise points in your question: first of all, you mention "copy" and "move" as if those terms had an absolute meaning, but usually each progrmaming language lingo redefines them to match their memory model (or don't use them when they're not relevant). Furthermore, the property of an object of "storing everything in itself" is itself a bit ill-defined. This overlaps with Rust's notion of a Copyable type, but yet again, this only makes sense in the context of Rust. I'm not this makes sense in C++.

Also, I'm not sure what you mean by "stack-and-heap-based memory allocation languages". Stack and heap are an abstraction provided by your operating system and (to some extent) by the hardware on your computer. Hence, except if you image very niche programming language that only run on niche operating system on niche hardware on which there is no notion of heap and stack, there is no non-stack-and-heap-based memory allocation programming language.

Indeed, if an object holds all its data internally, without referring to external data, duplicating and relocating the object will essentially yield the same result. This occurs because both operations will duplicate all the information contained in the object.
In the c++ code you provided, copying and moving EverythingInMyself will produce the same outcome because all data is held within the object itself.

At least in C++, this is usually true for classes without design mistakes. But since you can have arbitrary code in copy/move constructors/assignments, it can't be true for arbitrary classes.
One exception I can think of (where this isn't true and this isn't a design mistake) is resetting moved-from members to some default values.
